# How to replace a brace using sed in linux

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Suppose I have a file (say a.txt) whose text reads :

{I have a dream
today}

I want to replace the braces so that the file a.txt now looks like :

I have a dream
today

I tried using the sed expression **sed -i {s/{}//g}**, but it doesn't work. Is there a smart way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/8344060)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario you want to use a [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html), and include both brackets `{` and `}` in it:

```
sed -i 's/[{}]//g' a.txt
```